# SWT: Transparent shell makes widgets transparent too

Tags: java, swt, transparency

Using SWT, I set the shell transparency with `setAlpha(x)`. But then all widgets have become transparent too. Even adding a "all white" image as a composite background became transparent.
So I can't actually do anything on this window.

Does anyone have a clever idea how to bypass this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a standard behavior for window shells on Windows OS. But you can achieve what you want by setting regions on the Shell...

Have a look at this snippet: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/SWTShellcreateanonrectangularwindow.htm

Comment: Thanks. I was actually looking at that before coming here. What I want to achieve is an semi-transparent overlay on top of an existing shell, and in the middle a custom message/image. Do you think I can do that with the method you linked? Thanks.

Comment: Well did you try using two shells, one for the semi-transparent background and one for the custom message/icon?

Comment: Hmmmm... interesting. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Well- it kinda' works... my problem is I have a shell which generates an error --> this opens another shell. And now you've offered to open another shell, so I'm trying to use the SWT.ON_TOP in a smart way so I'll have the transparent shell on top of the existing shell, and the shell with the image on top the transparent shell.

Answer (score 6):

Is it possible that you are searching for something like [this](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/opal/wiki/InfiniteProgressPanel):

[image]

Or [this](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/opal/wiki/Panels):

[image]

Both are part of the [opal project](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/opal/).

Comment: Yep, the first one. Unfortunately, I can't use any "experiment" libraries, and they must work on both Windows and Linux.

Comment: The first one works on linux. If you aren't allowed to use this library, have a look at the source code. It shouldn't be too hard to reproduce.

Comment: This Opal project looks like a useful collection of utilities. Thanks for the useful link. You know any other such projects like this? I have seen other cool projects but they are usually very need specific. But this is a good collection of useful and generic utilities that can be used in a variety of applications.

Comment: @WaqasIlyas The only other one I know is [Nebula](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/).

Comment: Opal and Nebula are the biggest and best maintained swt custom widget libs. I found yet another one: [SWT-Appkit](http://fab1an.github.io/appkit/). It is not the newest, but has some pretty good stuff,specally if you want overlay.